# why this query blocked

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following query to insert row into table by copy the latest row.

but it blocked :

```
INSERT INTO tradeitem 
            (iteminfoid, 
             type, 
             userid, 
             cids) 
SELECT iteminfoid, 
       type, 
       userid, 
       cids 
FROM   tradeitem 
ORDER  BY tradeitemid DESC 
LIMIT  1;
```

I just want to explain why this blocked , does some lock circle occurred in this query ?

thanks for your wisdom :)

The primary key is tradeitemId

Comment: You cannot use queries inside query, declare it into a variable

Comment: which is your primary key?

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Can you publish your schema?

Comment: Yes, it also works for me, only one way for blocking it, if you try to insert contents with same primary key.

Comment: Your query is fine.  If it is not working, I'm guessing you have a unique index on one or more of the columns in the query.

Comment: @HendryTanaka: of course you can use queries inside queries. That's called a sub-query (or derived table).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh..I see. I will learn more. Thanks pal. Vote one for you

Comment: the tradeItemid is primary key

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the SQL fiddle link: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48cb6/2

Your query works fine:

```
INSERT INTO TradeItem (
    itemInfoId
    ,type
    ,userId
    ,cids
    )
SELECT itemInfoId
    ,type
    ,userId
    ,cids
FROM TradeItem
ORDER BY tradeItemId DESC limit 1;
```

Note that tradeItemId will be null after the new insert (Check whether tradeItemId is declared as not null field).

You may also need to check the primary key & unique index constraints.

Comment: tradeItemId is primary key, auto increment